# JSF with custom Annotation

Tags: jsf, annotations

I am using primefaces version 5 and I am adding messages regarding to a specific actions like save :

```
public void save(Tenant tenant) {
        tenantDao.save(tenant);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Save success"));
}
```

Since I had a lot of these actions I tried to simplify this by creating a custom annotation called Message:

```
@Target(Runtime)
@Retention(Method) 
public @interface Message {
   String value();
}
```

and in my dao class :

```
public class TenantDao {
    @Message("Saved Successfully")
    public Tenant save(Tenant t) {
        return em.save(t);
    }
}
```

To read this annotation I have overridden the ELResolver the method invoke

```
 public Object invoke(ELContext context,
                         Object base,
                         Object method,
                         Class<?>[] paramTypes,
                         Object[] params) {
    Object result = super.invoke(context,method,paramTypes,params);
    Method m = base.getClass().getMethod(method,paramTypes);
    if(m.getAnnotation(Message.class) != null) {
        addMessahe(m.getAnnotation(Message.class).value());
    }
    return result;
}
```

This was called in property (rendered, update, ..) but not in action listener
After a lot of debugging I discovered that the`actionListener` is called from `MethodExpression` class. So, I wrapped the `MethodExpression` class, and override the method invoke.
The problem now is that there are no way to retreive the class Method from `MethodExpression` class, also if I used the expression `#{tenantDao.save(tenant)}` the method `getMethodInfo` from `MethodExpression` will throw an exception.
Are there any way to read tAnnotation from any jsf context ?
I know that using Spring with AOP may solve this but I am not using Spring now.
Thanks

Comment: How is this PrimeFaces related? I don't see any PrimeFaces code

Comment: Primefaces is a jsf component. And the Code I am writting is a standard jsf
You can change the factory and the elresolver in a standard jsf
That what I have done by adding the factory tag in a faces-config.xml

Comment: PrimeFaces is a JSF component **suite**. And if the code you are writing is **standard** jsf, it is 100% not PrimeFaces related. I removed that tag...